# probem with nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a baremetal kubernetes cluster running on RHEL7 with one master and three worker nodes.
I am trying to setup [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) for the baremetal and everything looks good but for some reason, I still can't access my sample nginx deployment I created.

I followed the following steps:

1. Apply ingress-nginx baremetal
   kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
2. Verify that everything is working as expected in namespace ingress-nginx
   [image]
3. Tried visiting the http://NODEIP:30548 (since Nginx ingress exposed to 30548 on NodePort) and I get 404 not found. Tried it for all nodes in my cluster and get 404. I think that means a good sign that my ingress controller is working as expected.
4. Created a deployment as seen below:

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   labels:
>     run: nginx
>   name: nginx-test-deploy
> spec:
>   replicas: 3
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       run: nginx-test
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         run: nginx-test
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - image: nginx
>         name: nginx
> ```

5. Exposed Service

   kubectl expose deploy nginx-test-deploy --port 80
6. Created Ingress as seen below:

> ```
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: ingress-resource-1
> spec:
>   rules:
>   - host: nginx.example.com
>     http:
>       paths:
>       - backend:
>           serviceName: nginx-test-deploy
>           servicePort: 80
> ```

7. Made a Host Entry for nginx.example.com in my local computer pointing to one of my nodes in cluster

Instead of seeing nginx landing page, it just doesn't resolve at all.

Can someone please guide me to figure out what might be going on?

Also I see that on two worker nodes, I see that pods are in "Completed" status and one is running. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: Could you please try to add containerPort to your deployment, and then apply and expose it again? There is an [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/service/networking/run-my-nginx.yaml) and [kubernets documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) about exposing nginx deployment. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Jakub, I tried that and still no luck. I still can't access nginx.example.com

Comment: 1.I have a question regarding to `Also I see that on two worker nodes, I see that pods are in "Completed" status and one is running`, you mean ingress controller pods which are in above screen or your nginx pods?  2.Are your nginx pods healthy and running? 3.Can you show your /etc/hosts with the host entry? 4. Could you try with empty host, copy this `spec:
 rules:
 - host: 
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /
       backend:
         serviceName: nginx-test-deploy 
         servicePort: 80` and tell me if it works?